# Pass request from asp.net core to Angular app (same url)

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

This is an Asp.Net Core 2.2 site with an Angular application, same domain. I can see that if Angular and Asp.Net can handle (booth can handle) the same url (let’s say http://myapp.com/docs/names), and I write it down in the browser url, the Asp controller catches it, however, if I use the Angular routing (which handle its own URLs), Angular handles it. Curiously, this is what I need.

Sometimes my Asp.Net controller might opt not to handle de request and, instead, let Angular handles it.

Is it possible for ASP.Net Core to let the request just pass through to Angular?

Comment: `Is it possible for ASP.Net Core to let the request just pass through to Angular?` Do you mean that user enter url through browser address bar, then ASP.NET Core not handle this request on server and let Angular router to navigate to view/component on Angular client side?

Comment: Kind of. If the user write down the url, asp.net handle it. That's what happens now, and that's ok. But, sometimes, I need to let Angular to handle it AFTER asp.net decided so.